# Javascript array mapping, using multiple characters does'nt work

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, decode

So with this encoder and decoder I want to make it decode multiple characters, like numbers in the decoder part, but it seems like the limit is one character. So my question is how I can make the code notice when those 8 digits match and how to turn them into the correspondent letter. The encoder part is fully working. I have tried using quotes around the digits but that doesnt seem to work

HTML:

```
<h2> Encrypt: </h2>
<textarea type="text" id="Encrypted" style="text- 
transform:uppercase; resize: none; width: 350px;" 
onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" 
rows="10" ></textarea>  
<br><br>

<input type="button" name="EncryptButton" value="Encrypt" 
onclick="Encrypt()">

<br><br>

<textarea type="text" id="Decrypted" style="text-transform:uppercase; 
resize: none; width: 350px;"    
onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" rows="10"> 
</textarea>

<br><br>

<input type="button" name="DecryptButton" value="Decrypt" 
onclick="Decrypt()">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var map = {
A: '01011010 ', B: '01011001 ', C: '01011000 ',
D: '01010111 ', E: '01010110 ', F: '01010101 ',
G: '01010100 ', H: '01010011 ', I: '01010010 ',
J: '01010001 ', K: '01010000 ', L: '01001111 ',
M: '01001110 ', N: '01001101 ', O: '01001100 ',
P: '01001011 ', Q: '01001010 ', R: '01001001 ',
S: '01001000 ', T: '01000111 ', U: '01000110 ',
V: '01000101 ', W: '01000100 ', X: '01000011 ',
Y: '01000010 ', Z: '01000001 '
};

var map2 = {
01011010: "A", 01011001: "B", 01011000: "C",
01010111: "D", 01010110: "E", 01010101: "F",
01010100: "G", 01010011: "H", 01010010: "I",
01010001: "J", 01010000: "K", 01001111: "L",
01001110: "M", 01001101: "N", 01001100: "O",
01001011: "P", 01001010: "Q", 01001001: "R",
01001000: "S", 01000111: "T", 01000110: "U",
01000101: "V", 01000100: "W", 01000011: "X",
01000010: "Y", 01000001: "Z"
};

function Encrypt() 
{

var inputEncrypted = document.getElementById("Encrypted");
var EncryptedText = inputEncrypted.value;
var newText = "";

 for(var i=0; i < EncryptedText.length; i++) {
   switch(EncryptedText[i]) {
       case "A":
          newText += map.A;
          break;
      case "B":
          newText += map.B;
          break;
      case "C":
          newText += map.C;
          break;
      case "D":
          newText += map.D;
          break;
      case "E":
          newText += map.E;
          break;
      case "F":
          newText += map.F;
          break;
      case "G":
          newText += map.G;
          break;
      case "H":
          newText += map.H;
          break;
      case "I":
          newText += map.I;
          break;
      case "J":
          newText += map.J;
          break;
      case "K":
          newText += map.K;
          break;
      case "L":
          newText += map.L;
          break;
      case "M":
          newText += map.M;
          break;
      case "N":
          newText += map.N;
          break;
      case "O":
          newText += map.O;
          break;
      case "P":
          newText += map.P;
          break;
      case "Q":
          newText += map.Q;
          break;
      case "R":
          newText += map.R;
          break;
      case "S":
          newText += map.S;
          break;
      case "T":
          newText += map.T;
          break;
      case "U":
          newText += map.U;
          break;
      case "V":
          newText += map.V;
          break;
      case "W":
          newText += map.W;
          break;
      case "X":
          newText += map.X;
          break;
      case "Y":
          newText += map.Y;
          break;
      case "Z":
          newText += map.Z;
          break;
      case " ":
          newText += " ";
      default:
          newText += EncryptedText[i];
    };
 }

 inputEncrypted.value = newText;

 }

function Decrypt() 
{

 var inputDecrypted = document.getElementById("Decrypted");
 var DecryptedText = inputDecrypted.value;
 var newText2 = "";

 for(var o=0; o < DecryptedText.length; o++) {
   switch(DecryptedText[o]) {
        case "A":
          newText2 += map2.A;
          break;
      case "B":
          newText2 += map2.B;
          break;
      case "C":
          newText2 += map2.C;
          break;
      case "D":
          newText2 += map2.D;
          break;
      case "E":
          newText2 += map2.E;
          break;
      case "F":
          newText2 += map2.F;
          break;
      case "G":
          newText2 += map2.G;
          break;
      case "H":
          newText2 += map2.H;
          break;
      case "I":
          newText2 += map2.I;
          break;
      case "J":
          newText2 += map2.J;
          break;
      case "K":
          newText2 += map2.K;
          break;
      case "L":
          newText2 += map2.L;
          break;
      case "M":
          newText2 += map2.M;
          break;
      case "N":
          newText2 += map2.N;
          break;
      case "O":
          newText2 += map2.O;
          break;
      case "P":
          newText2 += map2.P;
          break;
      case "Q":
          newText2 += map2.Q;
          break;
      case "R":
          newText2 += map2.R;
          break;
      case "S":
          newText2 += map2.S;
          break;
      case "T":
          newText2 += map2.T;
          break;
      case "U":
          newText2 += map2.U;
          break;
      case "V":
          newText2 += map2.V;
          break;
      case "W":
          newText2 += map2.W;
          break;
      case "X":
          newText2 += map2.X;
          break;
      case "Y":
          newText2 += map2.Y;
          break;
      case "Z":
          newText2 += map2.Z;
          break;
      case " ":
          newText2 += " ";
      default:
          newText2 += DecryptedText[i];
     };
 }

   inputDecrypted.value = newText2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need raw encryption data without a space at the end, same goes for the keys of the decryption object, where the keys needs to be written as strings, because the leading zero is interpreted as octal number:

```js
var map2 = { 01011010: "A", 01011001: "B", 01011000: "C", 01010111: "D", 01010110: "E", 01010101: "F", 01010100: "G", 01010011: "H", 01010010: "I", 01010001: "J", 01010000: "K", 01001111: "L", 01001110: "M", 01001101: "N", 01001100: "O", 01001011: "P", 01001010: "Q", 01001001: "R", 01001000: "S", 01000111: "T", 01000110: "U", 01000101: "V", 01000100: "W", 01000011: "X", 01000010: "Y", 01000001: "Z" };

console.log(map2);
```

For getting a decryption value, you need to split by space and take the string as key for getting the decrypted value.

`onkeyup` does not need `javascript:` as prefix, because it expects Javascript by design.

For variable names and function who are not classes or instanciable functions (the ones, later used with `new` statement) starts usually with a small letter.

```js
var map = { A: '01011010', B: '01011001', C: '01011000', D: '01010111', E: '01010110', F: '01010101', G: '01010100', H: '01010011', I: '01010010', J: '01010001', K: '01010000', L: '01001111', M: '01001110', N: '01001101', O: '01001100', P: '01001011', Q: '01001010', R: '01001001', S: '01001000', T: '01000111', U: '01000110', V: '01000101', W: '01000100', X: '01000011', Y: '01000010', Z: '01000001'},
    map2 = { '01011010': "A", '01011001': "B", '01011000': "C", '01010111': "D", '01010110': "E", '01010101': "F", '01010100': "G", '01010011': "H", '01010010': "I", '01010001': "J", '01010000': "K", '01001111': "L", '01001110': "M", '01001101': "N", '01001100': "O", '01001011': "P", '01001010': "Q", '01001001': "R", '01001000': "S", '01000111': "T", '01000110': "U", '01000101': "V", '01000100': "W", '01000011': "X", '01000010': "Y", '01000001': "Z" };

function encrypt() {
    var inputEncrypted = document.getElementById("Encrypted"),
        text = inputEncrypted.value,
        encrypted = "",
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        encrypted += encrypted && ' ';
        encrypted += map[text[i]] || text[i];
    }
    inputEncrypted.value = encrypted;
}

function decrypt() {
    var inputDecrypted = document.getElementById("Decrypted"),
        code = inputDecrypted.value.split(' '),
        decrypted = "",
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        decrypted += map2[code[i]] || code[i];
    }
    inputDecrypted.value = decrypted;
}
```

```html
<h2>Encrypt:</h2>
<textarea type="text" id="Encrypted" style="text- 
transform:uppercase; resize: none; width: 350px;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" name="EncryptButton" value="Encrypt" onclick="encrypt()"><br><br>
<textarea type="text" id="Decrypted" style="text-transform:uppercase; 
resize: none; width: 350px;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" name="DecryptButton" value="Decrypt" onclick="decrypt()">
```